# htaccess redirect with query in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I've searched a lot of topics but can't find a solution/ don't know enough for this:

I want people to access and see:

```
www.educateforlife.org.uk/myimpact/meet/123
```

but for it to load:

```
www.educateforlife.org.uk/myimpact/meet/?u=123
```

I'm trying this:

```
RewriteRule ^myimpact/meet/([A-Z0-9\-_]+)/?$ /myimpact/meet/?u=$1 [L]
```

but I end up with a 404 (not even myimpact/meet is loading)

Comment: Hi sorry for late reply zx81, was expecting SF to email me when someone commented ... No, doesn't work. Still getting 404. I've tried putting your code before, after and in the WP <IfModule ..> but with no change ...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^myimpact/meet/([^/]+)/?$ /myimpact/meet?u=$1 [L]
```